# Convert mangled unicode in perl

Tags: perl, unicode

I have a listing of filenames where - due to bad conversion from unicode - some of the names are mangled.

This:

```
Naturalis_Biodiversity_Center_-_RMNH.ART.40_-_Gymnothorax_hepaticus_(RÃ¼ppell)_-_Kawahara_Keiga_-_1823_-_1829_-_Siebold_Collection_-_pencil_drawing_-_water_colour.jpeg
```

should read like this (notice the umlaut about halfway):

```
Naturalis_Biodiversity_Center_-_RMNH.ART.40_-_Gymnothorax_hepaticus_(Rüppell)_-_Kawahara_Keiga_-_1823_-_1829_-_Siebold_Collection_-_pencil_drawing_-_water_colour.jpeg
```

other cases are

```
GÃ¼nther  => Günther
ForsskÃ¥l => Forsskål
```

Is there a way to find and correct these cases with perl, apart from manual search and replace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The String is ISO-8859-1 encoded instead of utf8.
You could decode the string:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Encode qw(decode);
use utf8;
use DDP;

my $str = 'GÃ¼nther';
my $newStr = decode("iso-8859-1", $str);
p $newStr;
```

Output:

> Günther

Comment: `decode("iso-8859-1", $str)` is either a no-op or an error depending on the input. You actually want `decode("UTF-8, $str)`, which you effectively did using `use utf8;`